# Socket.io server response with multiple values

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I'm using react front end with nodeJs v6 backend, and socket.io-redis pub sub method. the connection is refused by the browser in this case.
I've this error:

`Failed to load https://api.mydomain.com/socket.io-client/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8vzD5C: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

im running on a front end react, backend nodeJs , with pub sub socket-redis connection
here are my response headers :

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, If-Modified-Since, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 104
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 18 Mar 2018 16:19:12 GMT
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`
may i know what did i do wrongly
apparently a connection can be established
but it breaks off immediately and keeps trying to reconnect in a loop (which i know why)
but why will my response header have mutliple values ?

Comment: You will have to show us your server code for us to identify what you did wrong there.  It looks like you might have some duplicate middleware both setting CORS headers.

Comment: @jfriend00 I actually sovled it by removing the add_header in my nginx file. May i know if this is a good way to solve it ?

Comment: OK, you can either write your own answer (if you think the answer would be useful to others) or you can delete your question.  It shouldn't be left just hanging out here with no answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 i thought i solved it, so in my ngnix site-enabled folder, theres an add_header to allow cors. however if by commenting it out, sockets gets connected correctly, BUT my API will have CORS issue ... god ... save me ... LOL

Answer (score -1):

this is what I've added in the above code : and i commented out the add_headers that were affecting the socket requests

```
set $cors '';
if ($request_uri !~ '^/socket.io-client') {
set $cors 'true';
}

if ($cors = 'true') {
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
}
```